# Executor is executing twice

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I am trying to run 2 threads simultaneously to achieve multithreading and my program is working, but I am in doubt as to why my program is prints to standard out twice.

Here is my code base:

```
public class SimpleExec {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(5);
        CountDownLatch countDownLatch6 = new CountDownLatch(5);
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        System.out.println("start" + LocalDateTime.now());
        executorService.execute(new MyThread("first ", countDownLatch));
        executorService.execute(new MyThread("Second", countDownLatch6));

        try {
            countDownLatch.await();
            countDownLatch6.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        System.out.println("end" + LocalDateTime.now());
        executorService.shutdown();

    }
}

class MyThread implements Runnable {
    String name;
    CountDownLatch cdl;

    public MyThread(String name, CountDownLatch cdl) {
        this.cdl = cdl;
        this.name = name;
        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println(name + " " + i);
            cdl.countDown();
        }
    }
}
```

And here's a sample of the program's output:

```
start 2018-08-18T08:41:51.867
first  0 // first time thread labeled 'first' prints 0 through 4
first  1
first  2
first  3
first  4
Second 0
Second 1
Second 2
first  0   // second time thread labeled 'first' prints 0 through 4 - why does it print again here?
first  1
Second 3
first  2
Second 4
first  3
first  4
end2018-08-18T08:41:51.870
Second 0
Second 1
Second 2
Second 3
Second 4
```

Answer (score 5):

Because you start a second thread for each of the Runnables in the constructor with `new Thread(this).start();`

The Runnables are started with the ExecutorService, no need for an additional `Thread.start()` just remove it.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because you spawn two threads *outside* the `ExecutorService` and execute your `Runnable` implementation on those *in addition to also submitting them for execution on the single thread associated with your `ExecutorService`*.

Remove `new Thread(this).start();` and you'll only see the printouts once. However, since you use `newFixedThreadPool(1)`, this effectively means that your program will run sequentially.

Answer (score 2):

## Let executor service manage threads

As others Answers have said, you are needlessly creating and managing threads. That is exactly the job of an executor service, to make concurrency easier by managing the creation, usage, and destruction of threads on your behalf.

## Example app

Reduce your `main` method to simply this:

```
try (
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 1 );
) {
    executorService.execute( new ZeroToFourCounter( "first " ) );
    executorService.execute( new ZeroToFourCounter( "Second" ) );
}
```

I believe there is no need for your use of [`CountDownLatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html). That class is used to make one or more threads wait until a set of operations in other threads completes. But with a thread pool of only one thread, the tasks will be completed in the order submitted. So no need to coordinate.

Change your [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) implementation’s `run` method to simply doing its intended job, counting 1-4 in a loop.

```
for ( int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++ ) {
    System.out.println( this.name + " " + i + " at " + Instant.now() );
}
```

No need to spawn a thread in that constructor of your [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html). You asked the executor service to manage a thread pool for you.

Complete application code:

```
package com.basilbourque.example;

import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class ExecDemo {

    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        System.out.println( "DEMO - Running `main`. " + Instant.now() );
        try (
            ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 1 );
        ) {
            executorService.execute( new ZeroToFourCounter( "first " ) );
            executorService.execute( new ZeroToFourCounter( "Second" ) );
            System.out.println( "DEMO - In `main`, executorService will now shutdown. " + Instant.now() );
        } 
    }
}

class ZeroToFourCounter implements Runnable {
    private String name;

    public ZeroToFourCounter ( String name ) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public void run () {
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++ ) {
            System.out.println( this.name + " " + i + " at " + Instant.now() );
        }
    }
}
```

When run:

> DEMO - Running `main`. 2018-08-18T08:20:42.916806Z
>
> DEMO - In `main`, asking executorService to shutdown(). 2018-08-18T08:20:42.986941Z
>
> DEMO - Ending `main`. 2018-08-18T08:20:42.987724Z
>
> first  0 at 2018-08-18T08:20:42.987058Z
>
> first  1 at 2018-08-18T08:20:43.027013Z
>
> first  2 at 2018-08-18T08:20:43.027090Z
>
> first  3 at 2018-08-18T08:20:43.027184Z
>
> first  4 at 2018-08-18T08:20:43.027259Z
>
> Second 0 at 2018-08-18T08:20:43.027413Z
>
> Second 1 at 2018-08-18T08:20:43.027544Z
>
> Second 2 at 2018-08-18T08:20:43.027673Z
>
> Second 3 at 2018-08-18T08:20:43.027784Z
>
> Second 4 at 2018-08-18T08:20:43.027891Z

Interesting… notice how these lines are *not* chronological! The `first  0` line captured a moment *earlier* than the line above it.

Note that calling [`ExecutorService::shutdown`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown()) does *not* interrupt the working threads. That call is a request to the executor to (a) stop accepting new work, and (b) finish the current work. To quote the doc:

> Initiates an orderly shutdown in which previously submitted tasks are executed, but no new tasks will be accepted. Invocation has no additional effect if already shut down.
>
> This method does not wait for previously submitted tasks to complete execution. Use awaitTermination to do that.

The call to `ExecutorService::shutdown` does not block. Nor does it check to see if the executor service ever shuts down. Consider if you would be better off calling `awaitTermination` as suggested to get the behavior of blocking until the executor service completes or fails to complete by the time-out.

In modern Java, `ExecutorService` is `AutoCloseable`. So we can use try-with-resources syntax to automatically close (shutdown).

## Not `LocalDateTime`

By the way, the `LocalDateTime` class is the wrong date-time class to use here. Lacking any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC, that class cannot represent an actual moment. Instead use `Instant` or `ZonedDateTime`.

I understand you are just doing some quick-and-dirty logging, so it is not important. But using `LocalDateTime` for a moment is a bad habit that could come back to haunt you later.

```
Instant.now()       // Capture current moment in UTC.
ZonedDateTime.now() // Capture the current moment in the JVM’s current default time zone.
```

Generally best to get in the habit of using [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) for most of your logging, storing, and exchanging of moments.